# Game Center challenges feature

Tags: ios, game-center

When implementing Game Center, do we need to implement all features such game challenges.  I have implemented Invite and Autoplay.  But just curious, do we need to handle all features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to implement all features.  But for the most part challenges are handled automatically if you have set up achievements or leaderboard scores.  Game Center will send your app messages about challenges (if it is in the foreground), but in general it handles the outcome without your app knowing about it.  (So if you submit a new score to a leaderboard which completes a challenge, it will notify the challenger that their challenge has been completed).

Comment: Would you take a look at this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874365/implementing-game-challenge-for-game-center

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that one as I haven't tried the multiplayer parts of GC.